# React Js : Failed to Compile

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I moved to windows 11 from Linux , so i imported all my code from Linux..to windows .
So whenever i try to run a react project , I get a compile error stating :

```
Failed to compile

./src/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react/jsx-dev-runtime' in 'D:\code\react-workspace\react-advanced-2020-master\src'

This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.
```

React. js is an open-source JavaScript library that is used for building user interfaces specifically for single-page applications. It's used for handling the view layer for web and mobile apps. React also allows us to create reusable UI components, *Had to write something as it was displaying error :)*

I tried `npm i -g react-scripts` and `npm clean install`

package.json

```
{
  "name": "tutorial",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: What does your package.json look like?

Comment: so inside your node_modules directory, you have a react folder, and inside that folder there is a file `jsx-dev-runtime.js`